# PHP alternative to loop inside a HEREDOC

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo, heredoc

I am trying to create loop inside of a HEREDOC in php. I know that it is not possible to do so, but it was the best way for me to tell what I need help for..
This is my code:

```
<?
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
$sth->execute();
echo <<<HERE_DOC
    [
    while($row = $sth->fetch()){ 
        echo '{"optionValue":"'.$row['field1'].'", "optionDisplay": "'.$row['field2'].'"},'; 
    }
    ]
HERE_DOC;
?>
```

and it tells me this

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /public_html/test.php on line 7
```

I think it returns this because it is not possible to create a loop inside a HEREDOC - but how do I do this otherwise..?

The script is driving by AJAX with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("select#state").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("test.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#city").html(options);
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

and the original test.php is like this:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == "1234") {
  echo <<<HERE_DOC
    [
    {"optionValue":"000", "optionDisplay": "a"},
    {"optionValue":"300", "optionDisplay": "s"},
    {"optionValue":"600", "optionDisplay": "d"},
    {"optionValue":"700", "optionDisplay": "cr"},
    {"optionValue":"500", "optionDisplay": "Gı"},
    {"optionValue":"400", "optionDisplay": "K"},
    {"optionValue":"800", "optionDisplay": "S"},
    {"optionValue":"900", "optionDisplay": "ik"},
    {"optionValue":"350", "optionDisplay": "Tu"}
    ]
HERE_DOC;
else if ($_GET['id'] == "2345") { etc......
```

The thing is that I already have all the data in an SQL database, and I would like to just return the data based on the id from previous select list since there is a lot of options.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a HEREDOC? Can't you just concatenate strings?

Comment: Oh look. A PHP question with some SQL in it. [Hello, Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: … and are you generating JSON by smashing together strings? Use `json_encode`!

Comment: it is from another tutorial here: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/ I only wanted to make it use my database instead of that I had to write everything again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the JSON yourself, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
<?
$json = array();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ // added PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    $json[] = array(
        'optionValue' => $row['field1'],
        'optionDisplay' => $row['field2']
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

P.S. Don't use `$_GET` directly like that.  You're vulnerable to SQL injection.  You're already using PDO, use it correctly.  You should do it like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

Comment: Yes, except you should probably be adding to the array inside the loop instead of replacing it every time...

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: Check your browser's dev tools, or add `console.log(j)` in your `$.getJSON` to make sure the JSON was fetched correctly.

Comment: It doesn't seem to that it returns data.. What should I do with the jQuery script then?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: Try to change `while($row = $sth->fetch()){` to `while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){`

Comment: When I am directly on the test.php with an id - it works.. but it still doesn't seem to that the script returns the data... nothing happens with the select list there is supposed to change options..

Comment: IT WORKS.. I am very sorry for my stupid comments - the only thing I missed is that I wasn't connected to the database (DOH!) -.-'

Comment: Hi Rocket.. Now I have tested it in every single browser - and of course our beloved IE works like shit.. It is the only browser that doesn't return the html to the select tag... Do you have any idea of how to do so?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: I don't see anything that could be wrong.  Try to `console.log(options)`, make sure it's valid HTML, IE gets mad if it's not.  You can also try `append` instead of `html`.  `$('select#city').empty().append(options)`.